# Hacer funcionar una validación (required) en un input de un formulario

Tags: javascript, required

Intenté hacer una validación como abajo pero antes de entrar al if me da este error:

> formulario.js:83 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

*Lo que intento hacer es que seleccionen una opción*.

```
    var resp1 = document.querySelector('input[name="1"]:checked').value;

    if (resp1.length > 0)  
    {  
      console.log(resp1);       
    }
    else if(resp1 === 'undefined')
    {
      console.log('Necesita seleccionar una opcion' + resp1);
    }
```

Comment: Pues básicamente te está diciendo que document.querySelector('input[name="1"]:checked') es null y no puedes acceder a sus propiedades. Básicamente, no está encontrando input[name="1"]:checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen dia!

El *pseudo-selector* `:checked` selecciona los inputs que están seleccionados, entonces al no seleccionar el input el método `querySelector` retorna `null`, ya que no hay ningún elemento que coincida con el selector.

Para realizar la validación con JavaScript seria de esta manera:

```js
// Selecciona el input sin importar si esta :checked o no
// si deseas seleccionar si o si un input que sea de tipo
// checkbox usa el siguiente selector:
// 'input[name="1"][type="checkbox"]'

const resp1 = document.querySelector('input[name="1"]');

// Tip: te recomiendo usar 'let' o 'const' en lugar de 'var'
// ya que su uso es considerado una mala practica.

// Los inputs de tipo checkbox tiene la propiedad 'checked'
// que es un boolean respectivamente de si esta o no
// seleccionada la casilla.
// Solo nos queda evaluar si esta o no seleccionada.

if (resp1.checked) {
  console.log(resp1.value)
} else {
  console.log('Necesita seleccionar una opción')
}
```

Los `input` ya tienen el atributo `required` por defecto por lo que al tratar de enviar el formulario te pedirá que selecciones la casilla, de esta manera:

```html
<form>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="1"
    value="Uno"
    required
  />
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

### BONUS

Este tipo de inputs independiente de estar o no seleccionado siempre te devolverá el valor "on" si, no le pones ningún valor en el atributo 'value' del HTML

Comment: Paul, convierte el código a snippet solo si es un código _reproducible_ en la pregunta/respuesta misma. En el caso de la pregunta, el cambio era innecesario, ya que el error no se visualizaba.

Comment: Gracias padaleina, lo tendré en cuenta, ya que soy nuevo en la plataforma 